# finding out memory consumption of a structure

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, structure

I am trying to figure out how much my structure will take memory consumption.Consider the following code

```
   struct tNode{
       short data;
       tnode *left;
       tnode *right;
       tnode *student;    
 }
```

so i know `data` is 2 bytes but what about `*left` ,`*right` and `*student` ,how much memory will they consume and how to calculate it.

Comment: Did `sizeof(tNode)` not give you a satisfactory result?

Comment: thank you for that useful function but i also need to know how it calculated that its taking 16 bytes.@StoryTeller

Comment: It's not a function, it's an operator. And if you see it now for the first time it may be prudent to take a step back from your project and read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for a couple of days.

Comment: ahh i see. arigato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [sizeof operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

> Returns size in bytes of the object representation of type

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

class tnode;

struct tNode {
       short data;
       tnode *left;
       tnode *right;
       tnode *student;
};

int main()
{

  std::cout << sizeof(tNode) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
32
```

Comment: but my computer is outputting 16 bytes

Comment: @newprogrammer the output is implementation dependent

Comment: @newprogrammer In C++, not every type is restricted to have a fixed size. They differ on different implementations.

Comment: @newprogrammer then your machine is probably using 32bit pointers while Ayxan's is using 64bit pointers.

Comment: @newprogrammer The compiler adjusts the size of the struct for performance reasons. More specifically, it pads bytes between members of the struct to ensure alignment of the members. More information here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object